# How do I define a common function within a Mocha it test?

Tags: mocha.js

I'm writing a Mocha test, and I'm trying to test a functionality by calling with different parameters.

How do I define a common function that can be called?
The following 2 definitions both give the error: "ReferenceError: commonfunction is not defined"

```
commonfunction: () => {
};

describe("Blah blah", async (accounts) => {
  it("should do something"), () => {
    commonfunction();
  });
});
```

```
describe("Blah blah", async (accounts) => {
  commonfunction: () => {
  };

  it("should do something"), () => {
    commonfunction();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not declaring a function. These are valid syntax for creating a function:

```js
function commonFunction () {
// do things
}

const commonFunction = () => {
// do things
}}

// immediately return true
const commonFunction = () => true

let commonFunction = () = {
// do things
}

// immediately return true
let commonFunction = () => true
```

This is not:

```js
commonFunction: () => {
}
```